# How to Display/Fetch Data on button click using AJAX in Python - AJAX

Tags: python, django

I am new to both ajax and django. I want to fetch phone number from database and want to display on template when click user the contact button. But in my case I am getting all the phone numbers in first button itself which is not correct. Because different persons have different phone numbers. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import listing_model
from .forms import listing_form
from django.http import HttpResponse


def submissions(request):
    tasks = listing_model.objects.all()
    form = listing_form()
    if request.method =='POST':
        form = listing_form(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
        return redirect('submissions')
    context = {'tasks':tasks, 'form':form}
    return render(request, 'submission.html', context)

#ajax
def contact(request):
        numbers= listing_model.objects.values('phone')
        return HttpResponse( numbers )
```

home.html

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block title %}Home{% endblock %}
{% block body %}
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <form method="GET" class="mx-auto" ><br>
    {{ user_filter.form }}<br><br>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left:250px">Search</button>
  </form>
</div>
</div>
<div>&nbsp; &nbsp;</div>
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
{% for task in tasks %}
<div class ="col-md-4">
<div class="card" style="width:300px">
<div class="card-body">
<h4 class="card-title">Title : {{ task.title }}</h4>
<div>Address : {{ task.address }}</div>
<div>City : {{ task.city }}</div>
<img src="{{ task.image.url }}" style="max-height:200px">
<div>&nbsp;</div>
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="request-btn">Contact</button>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#request-btn").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/listings/contact",
            type: "GET",
            datatype:"json",
            success: function(numbers){
                alert(numbers)
}
    });
    });
}); 
</script>

</div>
</div></div>
{% endfor %}
</div></div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You should pass the id of the person via ajax in data{id:" "} and in your views.py you should fetch the data of that particular id and then you should return the number in the success function. If you could share your models.py then I can try it out from my side.

Comment: Have you considered pagination?

Comment: <pre><code>from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class listing_model(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    address=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    city=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
    phone=models.IntegerField()
def __str__(self):
    return self.title</code></pre><br>@Karthik

Comment: No  I didn't considered pagination     @TechniCollins

Answer (score -1):

```
urls.py

    from django.contrib import admin
    from django.urls import path
    from ajax_with_djnago import views
    
    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('listings/contact/<str:id>', views.contact),
        path('', views.home)

]


views.py

    from django.shortcuts import render
    
    from .models import listing_model
    from django.http import JsonResponse
    
    
    def home(request):
        all_detail = listing_model.objects.all()
        print(all_detail)
        return render(request, 'index.html', context={'tasks': all_detail})
    
    
    # ajax
    def contact(request, id):
        numbers = listing_model.objects.get(id=id)
        return JsonResponse({'numbers': numbers.phone}

)

models.py


    from django.db import models
    
    
    # Create your models here.
    class listing_model(models.Model):
        title = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
        address = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)
        phone = models.IntegerField()
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title


index.html


    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            {% for task in tasks %}
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card" style="width:300px">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            {% for task in tasks %}
                                <h4 class="card-title">Title : {{ task.title }}</h4>
                                <div>Address : {{ task.address }}</div>
                                <div>City : {{ task.city }}</div>
                                <div>&nbsp;</div>
                                <button class="btn btn-primary"
                                        id={{ task.id }} onclick="showPopup('{{ task.id }}')">Contact
                                </button>
                                <p id="contact"></p>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                function showPopup(id) {
                                    $.ajax({
                                        url: "/listings/contact/" + id,
                                        method: 'GET',
                                        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': '{{ csrf_token }}'},
                                        success: function (data) {
                                            $('#contact').html(data['numbers']);
                                        }
    
                                    });
    
                                }
                            </script>
    
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
```

[For Complete Code Please check this link](https://github.com/Abhi904485/pallivi)